# scape value query

Tags: joomla2.5

Hi everyone in my getListQuery() method I have this query en SQL with error because I don´t know how to scape $language value

```
$query->from('`#__noticias` AS a');
$query->where('( a.idioma LIKE '.$language.' )');
```

I want to obtain this.

```
$query->from('`#__noticias` AS a');
$query->where('( a.idioma LIKE "es-ES" )');
```

any idea!

Comment: Downvoting because tags indicate SQL, but there's clearly other platforms at play here because that isn't SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Do it

```
 $lan = $db->Quote('%'.$db->escape($language, true).'%');
```

Finally

```
    $db = $this->getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $language =& JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag();
    $lan = $db->Quote('%'.$db->escape($language, true).'%');

    // Select the required fields from the table.
    $query->select(
            $this->getState(
                    'list.select', 'a.*'
            )
    );

    $query->from('`#__noticias` AS a');
    $query->where('( a.idioma LIKE '.$lan.' )');
```